# Help working out the best method of laying out this page section?

Tags: html, css

My mind's drawing a blank on the best way to possibly lay out the design in terms of code structure ive attached to this post, can this be achieved using `<dl>` or `<ul>` tags or would there have to be divs etc?

All suggestions appreciated.

http://www.flickr.com/photos/62570778@N04/5719672246/in/photostream/

Comment: I just read your edit, and I suggest (especially if you're not experienced) to go for a `div` only solution. You can style them in so many ways, check for the `float` property and then the `clear` property.

Comment: @jackjoe My post really is about finding out how to get away from the overuse of divs thats why I've also suggested the possibility of doing this layout with dl or ul tags. Just trying to work out what would work best with the least amount of clutter

Comment: I don't think you can "overuse" divs. If it's within standards and if you can style it correctly I don't mind it. For such a simple layout it wont definetly be the case of overuse, at least IMO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I might do it like this: http://jsfiddle.net/Drnsk/

```
<ul class="userDetails">
    <li>
        <h4>My Vitals</h4>
        <div class="social">social</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>Where I'm From <span>USA</span></h4>
        <div class="map">map</div>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>My Name <span>John</span></h4>
    </li>
    <li>
        <h4>My Age <span>29</span></h4>
    </li>
</ul>

.userDetails {
    width: 440px;
    background: #fff;
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 9px 9px 0 9px
}
.userDetails li {
    overflow: hidden;
    border-top: 1px solid #000;
    padding: 9px 0;
}
.userDetails li:first-child {
    padding-top: 0;
    border-top: 0
}
.userDetails h4 {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative
}
.userDetails h4 span {
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: 20px;
    width: 120px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0; right: 0
}


.userDetails .social, .userDetails .map {
    height: 40px;
    color: #fff;
    background: #f0f
}
```

Comment: IMHO a heading inside a list, although valid HTML, does not seem right.

Comment: @August Karlstrom: I actually agree (I think). I wasn't sure whether to make it a `h<low number>` or simply a `span`.

Answer (score 1):

a div is a tag :)

And there are so many ways to achieve that. You need to create the appropriate tags (divs in this case) and then style them with CSS.

To get you started I suggest this:

```
<div class="myvitals">
    vitals content here
</div>
<div class="where">
    where content here
</div>
<div class="name">
    name content here
</div>
<div class="age">
    age content here
</div>
```

then the CSS:

```
.myvitals {
   {your properties here}
}

and the definition of the other classes here.
```

Understand that this is basic for someone that has some experience, otherwise you need to study a bit about html and CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend the [960 Grid System](http://960.gs/) and use divs to lay everything out.  Its a really powerful development tool to layout a design.

Answer (score -1):

If it wasn't for the map (which occupies two columns) I would definitely use a table for the facts section. A reasonable compromise is probably to use div elements as in the solution posted by jackJoe.